# Qt Designer freeze (lockup) when selecting "Choose Resource..."

Tags: windows, qt, qt-designer

#### Problem

Qt Designer is locking up when selecting a image from Resource, stops responding, just 
makes Windows bing sound.

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem with Qt Designer, or a decent work-around?

I've only tried `Label.pixmap` and `PushButton.icon` so far.

Every time I select this option the entire Designer locks up. It seems like it's trying to display a modal selection dialog box, but I can't see it anywhere.

"Choose File..." option works fine but isn't a convenient option.

I have had Designer working properly in the past. 
My project was paused for a couple of months, during this time I lost my Qt build due a complete HDD failure, and have restored from a zip-backup I'd made. I can still build against Qt libs.
Since then hasn't worked.

I also built for Linux and the same `.ui` files can be editing properly with Ubuntu 10.10.

#### Environment

- Qt v4.7.1
- VS2008 SP1, I built my own build of Qt
- VS addin (same symptoms for v1.1.7 and v1.1.9)
- Win7-x64 Pro

#### Tried (without success):

- rebuilding Qt from source
- manually editing `.ui` file as suggested here: http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/…crashes-Creator
- running Designer from installed folder
- watched `designer.exe` in procmon (seems to be doing a lot registry lookups for `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`, but nothing that looks significant)

This is really hurting me, help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

The 'lockup' was caused by Designer opening a modal resource dialog. However, since last using Designer, I had moved my second screen to the other side of my primary screen, the modal dialog was open in the old screen (no longer connected) so I couldn't see it.

Resolution: Windows-key + Left-key moved the missing dialog back onto a connected screen.